# Fenced Code Block Styling in Ordered List

Tags: jekyll, octopress

I am using fenced-code-blocks in an ordered-list. The code I have is

````
1. Download and extract `jre-7u21-linux-i586.gz` to `/usr/java`

    Your `/usr/java` directory should look similar to this,

    ```
    /usr/java
      |-- jdk1.6.0_43
      |-- jre1.7.0_21
    ```

2. Tell `alternatives` that you have installed a new `java`
````

Using `octopress` with the `markdown` config set to `redcarpet` (instead of the
default `rdiscount`), the following is what I see.

[image: screenshot]

As you will notice, the "line-number vertical line" got moved all the way to the
right in the code block.

1. How do I "move" the line-number area back to the left, and actually show the
   line number?
2. Or, if that's not possible, can you please help me remove the
   "right vertical bar" altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here : https://github.com/imathis/octopress/pull/814

Hope it will help.

---

I found the best solution might be using html tags instead. Using plugins to solve this is so confusing.See my [example1](https://github.com/abop/abop.github.com/edit/source/source/_posts/2013-05-15-debug-with-jekyll-rubygem.markdown) [example2](https://github.com/abop/abop.github.com/edit/source/source/_posts/2013-03-05-How_to_Recover_Files_Deleted_by_Mistake_in_Git.md)

````
<ol>
<li> Download and extract `jre-7u21-linux-i586.gz` to `/usr/java`

    Your `/usr/java` directory should look similar to this,

    ```
    /usr/java
      |-- jdk1.6.0_43
      |-- jre1.7.0_21
    ```
</li>
<li> Tell `alternatives` that you have installed a new `java` </li>
</ol>
````

Comment: I copied and pasted the changed files in the commit. Unfortunately, it didn't work out. I don't understand the code enough to figure out what it's trying to do. Glancing through the comments, it seems this might be fixed in the `2.1` branch. I really do appreciate your effort. Thank you.

Comment: I use original html tag to handle this.Write list content in `<ol><li></li></ol>`. It will handle whatever markdown fragment you want to put into an ordered list.